# How to pass a reference array of variables to task?

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to pass a reference array of variables. It works fine with a reference to variable, but not with an array of variables. The goal with the task is to be able to take an array of variables, and read them on every clock edge.

So this code does not work

```
module tb;
  logic clock = 0;
  logic a = 0;
  logic b = 0;

  task automatic read_vars(ref logic clock, input int clock_edges = 10,
                           const ref logic signal_array[]);
      repeat (clock_edges) begin
        @(posedge clock) $display("@TIME: %t Clock edge", $time);
        for (int i = 0; i < signal_array.size(); i++) begin
          $display("Variable %0d: %0b", i, signal_array[i]);
        end
      end
  endtask

  always begin
    #1 clock = 1;
    #1 clock = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #3 b = 1;
    #3 b = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #7 a = 1;
    #7 a = 0;
  end

  initial begin

    fork
      read_vars(.clock(clock), .signal_array({a, b}));
    join_none

    #1000;

    $finish();
  end
endmodule
```

I get the following error

```
      read_vars(.clock(clock), .signal_array({a, b}));
                                             |
xmvlog: *E,BADRFA (tb.sv,25|45): invalid ref argument usage because actual argument is not a variable.  [SystemVerilog].
        module worklib.tb:sv
```

But this code works.

```
module tb;
  logic clock = 0;
  logic a = 0;
  logic b = 0;

  task automatic read_vars(ref logic clock, ref logic a, ref logic b, input int clock_edges = 10);
    repeat (clock_edges) begin
      @(posedge clock) begin
        $display("@TIME: %t Clock edge", $time);
        $display("a = %b ", a);
        $display("b = %b ", b);
      end
    end
  endtask

  always begin
    #1 clock = 1;
    #1 clock = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #3 b = 1;
    #3 b = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #7 a = 1;
    #7 a = 0;
  end


  initial begin

    fork
      read_vars(.clock(clock), .a(a), .b(b));
    join_none

    #1000;

    $finish();
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: @Mikef It would be nice to get it working with a dynamic array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible in verilog.
First of all, having a reference to an array will not help in solving the issue. Arrays contain values of something. So creation of an array with {a,b} will just copy values of the variables into the array and updating variables will not be reflected in any case.

What you are after is an array of references to variables, which is impossible in a verilog.

However, class variables are always reference. So, you can wrap your vars in a class in test bench. Here is a modified example of yours:

```
class V;
  logic val;
endclass:V 

module tb;
  V a = new;
  V b = new;
  V arr[] = '{a, b};
  
  logic clock = 0;
  //logic a = 0;
  //logic b = 0;

  task automatic read_vars(ref logic clock, input int clock_edges = 10,
                           V signal_array[]);
      repeat (clock_edges) begin
        @(posedge clock) $display("@TIME: %t Clock edge", $time);
        for (int i = 0; i < signal_array.size(); i++) begin
          $display("Variable %0d: %0b", i, signal_array[i].val);
        end
      end
  endtask

  always begin
    #1 clock = 1;
    #1 clock = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #3 b.val = 1;
    #3 b.val = 0;
  end

  always begin
    #7 a.val = 1;
    #7 a.val = 0;
  end

  initial begin
    fork
      read_vars(.clock(clock), .signal_array(arr));
    join_none

    #1000;

    $finish();
  end
endmodule
```